# Audio Steganography

Tags: cipher, steganography, audio

A simple question, without a simple answer.
Rome would be the obvious answer, but it is not THE answer.
A picture contains a 1000 words, this audio contains one.

https://youtu.be/HiH4_A0xq40

> Audio Steganography can hide pictures or words inside music, this one is on it's own, no masking tune. you'll need to SEE this audio to even begin to decipher what the answer is.

> Even if you can guess the answer, you'll never KNOW it is right without the picture contained within and a Cipher to decode it.

> Once you have the picture, look to Sherlock to get the answer.

If you get the picture, take a snapshot so we can all see it. Then answer the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word is

> AMBER

The emphasis in the puzzle on visualizing the audio motivated a spectogram of the audio revealing

> [image: spectrogram]

which combined with the Sherlock reference immediately brings to the mind

> *The Adventure of the Dancing Men* by A. C. Doyle.

In this short story, the antagonist uses

> the dancing men cipher

to encrypt messages. Though the original publication doesn't reveal all the letters - and one may have some fun trying to figure out the key,  if one thinks of it sooner, a google search would quickly reveal

> [image]
>  the key.

Thanks to @flinty [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/226539/65285), there might be a further hidden meaning. On cleaning up the spectrogram, one sees that
the dancing men might be

> [image]
>  *Star Wars Troopers*

goofing around.

Comment: You are totally correct, and they are dancing storm troopers. The YMCA Storm Trooper image inspired me to incorporate them into that cipher. Thank you for the link too, I was looking for a way to get a clearer image.